# SDWebImage get all stored url

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage and I need to have all image url which images are stored on device.

```
- (NSString *)cachePathForKey:(NSString *)key inPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSString *filename = [self cachedFileNameForKey:key];
    return [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
```

I can know path and I see all images but they are stored after url is encoded or hashed. So, I see like this.

How shall I get list of image url that's images are stored on device?

[image]

Comment: why exactly do you need this information? sdweb image stores the urls as key and images as values so that next time you request the same url you dont have to download and use the cached ones. I dont think sdweb exposes the urls as you are asking.

Comment: It is because I have like 5 groups (e.g T1ABC, T2ABC, T3ABC). As long as url consist of T1ABC, I want to clear that image from cache. That is why I need to first have list of image url stored. Is it a good way to do? Any alternative ?

Comment: Because i need to iterate all cached keys to delete some of them matching the regular expressionUrl. Does SDWebImage support on clear cache by regular expression?